# NHibernate - Mapping a Complex Type so that is Serialized as String

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, mapping

I have a DTO Object with a Property of Type "ObservableDictionary" named "Test" which is also Serializable!

The DTO Field "Test" is now mapped to a Datbasfield "Test" which is of Type nvarchar(max).

When I save and load also everything works fine, but the serialization in the database is not readable, it's filled with special chars.

Is it possible to tell NHibernate to use the XMLSerializer?

Comment: Look at this http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/ it will get you started, the thing you want is a custom user type

Comment: Is that so complex to achieve such a simple Task?

Comment: I wouldn't say its a simple task, I think its great that NHibernate is so extensible. Glad you got answer.

Comment: But I think it should give at Attribute wich tells To Standartly Serialize a Complex Type as String instead of Binary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it! With Help from Rippo!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.SqlTypes;
using NHibernate.UserTypes;

namespace MCC.Common.DL.BaseObjects
{
    public class SerializableUserType<originalType> : IUserType
    {
        public SqlType[] SqlTypes
        {
            get
            {
                SqlType[] types = new SqlType[1];
                types[0] = new SqlType(DbType.String);
                return types;
            }
        }

        public System.Type ReturnedType
        {
            get { return typeof(originalType); }
        }

        public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            if (x == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return x.Equals(y);
            }
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object x)
        {
            return x.GetHashCode();
        }

        public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
        {
            string txt = (string)NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
            return StringSerializer<originalType>.DeSerialize(txt);
        }

        public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
                return;
            }
            var wrt = StringSerializer<originalType>.Serialize((originalType)value);

            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, wrt, index);
        }

        public object DeepCopy(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            return StringSerializer<originalType>.DeSerialize(StringSerializer<originalType>.Serialize((originalType)value));            
        }

        public bool IsMutable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
        {
            return original;
        }

        public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
        {
            return cached;
        }

        public object Disassemble(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

and this I use in Fluent like :

```
Map(x => x.ScriptedTagScript).CustomType(typeof(SerializableUserType<ObservableDictionary<string, string>>));
```

And you need this helper class:

```
public class StringSerializer<T>
{
    public static string Serialize(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return string.Empty;

        // XML-Serialisieren in String
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        // Serialisieren in MemoryStream
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Indent = true;

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

        XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, namespaces);

        // Stream in String umwandeln 
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(ms);
        r.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return r.ReadToEnd();
    }        

    public static T DeSerialize(string txt)
    {
        T retVal = default(T);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
        {
            return retVal;
        }

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(txt);
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
            retVal = (T) ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            xmlReader.Close();
            stringReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return retVal;
    }        
}
```